# Cannot find symbol class WorkbookSettings

Tags: android, excel

I am trying to export the SQLite data to the Excel file. 
I have added code for export inside button click event.
My code is as follows :

```
 mBtnExport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String fileName = "Data.xls";

            //Saving file in external storage
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/ExportToExcel");

            //create directory if not exist
            if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }

            //file path
            File file = new File(directory, fileName);

            WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
            wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
            WritableWorkbook workbook;
            Log.i("Path=================", file.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
                //Excel sheet name. 0 represents first sheet
                WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("User Detail", 0);

                try {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "")); // column and row
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 0, "Age"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
                        //String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TODO_SUBJECT));
                        String title = mData.get(i).getmName();
                        String age = mData.get(i).getmAge();


                        sheet.addCell(new Label(0, i + 1, title));
                        sheet.addCell(new Label(1, i + 1, age));
                    }


                    //closing cursor

                } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (WriteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                workbook.write();
                try {
                    workbook.close();
                } catch (WriteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Exported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

dependences in **build.gradle** :

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'jexcelapi:jxl:2.6'
compile 'com.madgag:sc-light-jdk15on:1.47.0.3'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.7'
```

}

**errorlog** :

```
Error:(218, 17) error: cannot find symbol class WorkbookSettings
Error:(218, 51) error: cannot find symbol class WorkbookSettings
Error:(220, 17) error: cannot find symbol class WritableWorkbook
Error:(223, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable Workbook
Error:(225, 21) error: cannot find symbol class WritableSheet
```

What is the problem here ? Is there any library issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue and solved the issue by adding the latest jexcel jar.          I downloded latest zip file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/, extracted the jxl.jar, created a lib folder in Android Studio and pasted the jar int he lib folder. Finally select the jar, right click and select 'add as library'. Rebuild the project and the error should get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine there, I just have to do **Add as library** to all the .jar files included in libs folder by right clicking the particular .jar file.